# How do I determine the manufacture date for my Giant Rincon mountain bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano

I have a giant Rincon men's mountain bike (serial number GU675673) with a straight crossbar (not inclined) like most I've seen online. I am trying to determine the date of manufacture in order to determine its value today.

Comment: You might check [here](https://bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/search?content=Rincon).  Looks like '97 and '98 had flat top tubes.

Comment: If you know the original components that were in it, that will usually narrow down the date quite a bit.

Comment: The value of a '97 bike is what a possible customer is willing to pay, unless the components and the frame are sought-after high range items.

Comment: https://www.bikeforums.net/general-cycling-discussion/437466-giant-date-manufacture-code.html Note second response.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most automobiles bike model years are best described as "fluid". Many years the only difference was what colors were available. As the model year comes to a close, parts may become unavailable so parts slated for the next model year may have been used. There are several resources I use but mostly rely on Bikepedia and BicycleBlueBook.  Both of these require an estimate of the age to get a close approximation. You may still be no closer than a 2-3 year range. In general used bike prices will vary a considerable amount based on region and time of year. When most bikes get to be 10 or 15 years old there is little value added for a COMP versus a SPORT model. A check of your local Craigs List may give you an idea of local value. You have to realize that the listings will have an asking price which may be unrealistic.